# I'm building a car game I want to move a car through the keyevent , the algorithm is okay, but the car doesn't move

Tags: java, android, game-physics

the main class is :

```
public class test extends Activity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new Game(this,null));
}
```

}

the Game class is extended from the view class to allow us to draw the car and set its position, and I called the onkey method to control the direction and the angle of the car

```
public class Game extends View {
private Paint paint= new Paint();
float x,y;
float speed = 5,angle = 0,mod = 0;
Bitmap car;
Boolean b=false;
public Game(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    try { // here I call the car image as a bitmap object
        AssetManager assetManager=context.getAssets();
        InputStream inputStream= assetManager.open("car.png");
        BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444;
        car=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream,null,options);
        inputStream.close();
        Log.d("Bitmap Text", "bobrgb888.png format: "+car.getConfig());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    }
 }

       @Override
       protected void   onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
       x += (speed*mod) * Math.cos(Math.PI/180 * angle);
           y += (speed*mod) * Math.sin(Math.PI/180 * angle);
       canvas.rotate((float) (Math.PI/180 * angle));
       canvas.drawBitmap(car,-(car.getWidth()/2), -(car.getHeight()/2), null);
       canvas.restore();
      }
          public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN:              
            break;
        case KeyEvent.ACTION_UP:
            {if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A ||               event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_B)
            {
                this.mod = 0;
            }}
            break;

        case KeyEvent.ACTION_MULTIPLE:{
            if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A)
            {
                mod = 1;
            }
            if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_B)
            {
                mod = -1;
            }
            if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_C)
            {
                angle -= 5;
            }

            if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_D)
            {
                angle+=5;
            }
            }
            break;
        }
        invalidate();
        return event.getKeyCode() != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK;
    }
}
```

I set the next point's x and y 
I rotate the image,following the chosen angle 
I draw the car in the current position.
when the keys A or B, are up, the car stops
when the key is pressed for a long time ( A,B,C,D) , the angle and the direction change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(View view, Editable arg1, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
```

instead of this:

```
public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
```